# How to make nginx wait for response, when response time can be different?

Tags: java, nginx

There is `Java` on project `server-side`. I have some endpoints which allow to generate csv files(lets say user records from db). File size can be different, because there can be applied filters. When filters are applied and file is not too big it works correctly, but when file is big it takes 1,5min to generate it, but `nginx` timeout is 30 sec, so `nginx` does not wait for server response and reports with `500`. Of course `nginx`-timeout can be increased, but this is not secured. Is it possible somehow to make `nginx` waiting more without touching its timeout param?

Comment: “Of course nginx-timeout can be increased, but this is not secured.” can you explain what you mean by this? NGINX has multiple timeout configuration settings, and you may be able to increase only `proxy_read_timeout`. Alternatively, if you are able to stream the response as it is generated, this might avoid triggering the timeout.

Comment: @TimMoore yes, I'm talking about proxy_read_timeout. I suppose this is not very good idea to increase it?(from point of security)what do you mean under response stream? Java-reactive streams?

Comment: I'm asking what the specific security concern is. It sounds like increasing `proxy_read_timeout` is exactly what you're asking for, so I'm trying to understand why that isn't a suitable solution for you, in order to try to suggest an alternative that doesn't have the same problem. Pardon my ignorance about the risk, but the only thing I can imagine is increased risk of DoS attacks with long-running requests. It sounds like long-running requests are normal and expected in this application.

Comment: What I mean about streaming the response is writing partial results to the response as they are available. This could involve using reactive streams, but doesn't have to. For example, writing each row of the CSV to the response before calculating the next one, if that's possible for this application. If each row can be generated within the 30 second timeout, that should avoid triggering the timeout, which resets whenever nginx can read data from your server's response.

Comment: Maybe it's also worth pointing out that `proxy_read_timeout` can be configured in a [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) context, if you don't want it to apply globally to the server, but just to a particular URL pattern.